# AJAX Form duplicate entries on submission

Tags: php, ajax, duplicates

I've got a PHP form set up and it works fine on it's own but now that I've hooked it up with AJAX I'm getting duplicate submissions when someone submits the form so even though they've only submitted the form once it's added the details to the database multiple times.

From my testing it seems as though its sending the data twice but looking at the submissions from other people it's possible that it's doing it more than twice under certain circumstances but I haven't been able to replicate that.

Here is the code I was using initially:

```
$("#email-gather").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "https://www.ruroc.com/emailgather.php";

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#email-gather").serialize(),
               complete: function(data) { 
                    $('.email-win input.button').val("submitted").attr('disabled', 'disabled').css({'background-color' : '#b34c4c','text-shadow' : 'none'});
               }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have had a look around to find a solution and I saw a few people with similar issues saying that .live should be used instead of .submit so I amended my code this this:

```
$( "#email-gather" ).live( "submit", function() {

  event.preventDefault();
  var url = "https://www.ruroc.com/emailgather.php";

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#email-gather").serialize(),
           complete: function(data) { 
                $('.email-win input.button').val("submitted").attr('disabled', 'disabled').css({'background-color' : '#b34c4c','text-shadow' : 'none'});
           }
    }); 
});
```

However this also resulted with the same issue so I'm hoping you might have a solution to this issue. I appreciate any help you can provide on the matter.

Comment: you probably need a unique index

Comment: The `e.preventDefault();` need to be called BEFORE you run the async `.ajax` call. in first fragment, and then DONT run `$("#email-gather").submit(function(e) { }` at the end

Comment: In second fragment you have things in the right order, but you do not have an `event` parameter passed in `function()` ___This should be generating a compile error I would have thought___

Comment: Thanks for responding, the second submission in the first section was a typo so please ignore that bit. My apologies.

I tried moving the preventDefault to above the ajax call but it didn't make any change and passing "event" in the function in the second segment also produces a duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

In the second part of code (that should work), you have event.preventDefault but event is not defined. try to add function(event) and it must work.

Else in the first one, you can put the prevent default before ajax call and take away the second submit. You need to add a return true in the ajax function to tell you script that the submit was successfull.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. I tried passing "event" through the function but it also sends a duplicate entry unfortunately.

Comment: Did you had the return true in the complete function ?

Comment: $( "#email-gather" ).live( "submit", function(event) {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = "https://www.ruroc.com/emailgather.php";

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#email-gather").serialize(),
           complete: function(data) { 
                $('.email-win input.button').val("submitted").attr('disabled', 'disabled').css({'background-color' : '#b34c4c','text-shadow' : 'none'});
                return true;
           }
    }); 
});